# Executing A function for all elements of an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, function, loops

Hey guys i have an array consisting of elements like below

`var arr = ['america','france','house','paris','table','new york']`

and i want to verify from my database if all are state or country or a capital

this is my example code to check for a single element

`let isValid = await db.worldDb.verifyQuery(query);`

`let verified;`
`['state','capital','country'].includes(isValid.response)? verified = true : verified = false;`

i want to pass the above code to all the element in the array and create a general function, so if any failed the test then the function will return false but if all passed then it retutn true.

Comment: It sounds like you want .every() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Promise.all` is exactly what you need.

```
var arr = ['america','france','house','paris','table','new york']

try {
    await Promise.all(arr.map(async a => {
        const isValid = await db.worldDb.verifyQuery(query);

        const verified = ['state','capital','country'].includes(isValid.response);

        if(!verified) throw new Error();
    }));
    // here is ok
} catch(e) {
    // here is not verified
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use Array.every() for this. It works like a foreach loop but if the callback function evaluates false for any of the elements in the array, the every function returns false.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every